# Unable to see mongo collections

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have on DB in mongodb. It's size is 7GB but when I run following commands result is zero. Anyone know the other way to check what's there in that db?

```
use insights
show collections
```

Comment: run command show dbs, see if you type correct db name

Comment: @mehta-rohan yes I selected proper db. Even I copied db name and pasted it. Still, it wasn't working.

Comment: I don't know exact issue but I restarted db and it worked.